# accessing the arguments of a function passed as param

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

I have a react component, where I need to verify that one of the props should be a function with certain type of params.

I am already using prop types in my setup, so I though a custom validator function can help me verify this as well.

This is how I am trying to verify the function signature of the prop

```
children: (props, propName, componentName) => {
    let error;
    const prop = props[propName];
    if (typeof prop !== "function") {
      error = new Error("expected children to be a function");
    }

    // console.log(prop.length);
    if (prop.length === 0) {
      console.log(prop.length);
      error = new Error("expected children to be a function with 1 argument");
    }

    // don't know how to verify the type of arguments
    // can't use prop.arguments in strict mode

    return error;
  }
```

Any pointers on how I can access the arguments of the function passed in children prop, and then verify if it is `typeof 'boolean'` ?

Comment: Does it matter? Not trying to be a PITA, but I'm wondering if this is your problem or the caller's problem to ensure they figure it out? What if their function defines 2 parameters but handles the case where you call it with just one? Or what if they handle `N` arguments passed in, internally within their function (but define none)?

Comment: it might not matter in specific cases, but I am just looking at a general answer for a situation where I can read the arguments of a function passed in as param. also isn't this the point about the whole prop types setup anyway, I could also expect the consumer to pass prop1 as string or prop2 as boolean, but I write proptypes for that, why not for functions then?